# Glassfish 4.12 Internal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, glassfish, apache-commons

I am trying to deploy sample Java EE Cargo Tracker application 
https://github.com/javaee/cargotracker

I am able to deploy it by executing maven, which build project completely
    mvn package cargo:run

However when I am trying to deploying application from IntelliJ Idea on Glassfish 4.1.12 I am getting

```
Internal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate. Please see server.log for more details.
```

My pom contains

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Tried 3.4 and 3.6, does not help, application fails to deploy with above error

This is configuration of artifact in IntelliJ IDEA

[image]

Project -> Artifact

[image]

Exploded WAR details

[image]

Comment: Make sure the jar from this dependency is deployed on the server, it must be present in the artifact that IntelliJ IDEA deploys, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html. Adjust artifact configuration if needed.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have updated my question with the details about artifact configuration. Please take a look, thank you.

Comment: It doesn't show which libraries are included in  the artifact, the page I've linked refers to the different configuration dialog than you've provided.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have updated question, including screenshot.

Comment: The screenshot shows that war artifact includes exploded artifact, but it doesn't show what libraries are added to the exploded artifact.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks, updated.

Comment: It appears to be a bug in IntelliJ IDEA artifact building. If you check the artifact output directory, you will not find any jar dependencies inside, probably related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173062. You can use 2017.1 version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/previous.html or build the artifact using Maven and use External Source deployment option in IntelliJ IDEA to deploy the war file that was built using Maven.

Answer (score 0):

may be old or previous dependency occurring the issue so delete `.m2` folder and use `commons-lang3` version `3.5` update maven project and rebuild it and run it.

Comment: I have already try that, I think the problem is that I am deploying war in a wrong way.